# Why do i get an error react-scripts: not found on github actions CI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the following package.json files for my app:

Client folder:

```
``{
  "name": "nasa-fe",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "arwes": "^1.0.0-alpha.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "nth-check@1.0.2": "2.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public&& react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --passWithNoTests",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Server folder:

```
 {
  "name": "nasa-project-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nasa mission control api",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles",
    "test-watch": "jest --watch",
    "watch": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "cluster": "pm2 start src/server.js -i max"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv-parse": "^5.3.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.4",
    "mongose": "^0.0.2-security",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "pm2": "^5.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3"
  }
}
```

and root folder:

```
{
  "name": "nasa-exploration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This a full stack project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "set BUILD_PATH=../server/public && npm run build --prefix client && npm start --prefix server",
    "deploy-cluster": "npm run build --prefix client && npm run cluster --prefix server",
    "server": "npm run watch --prefix server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "watch": "npm run server & npm run client",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/yayoamigo/Nasa-exploration.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/yayoamigo/Nasa-exploration/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/yayoamigo/Nasa-exploration#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "arwes": "^1.0.0-alpha.5",
    "axios": "^1.2.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

as you can see I have react-scripts in every folder but get this error regardless, I tried to reinstall the dependencies, change the scripts and nothing. The weird things is when I npm run build on my PC it works
[image]

Comment: What does your workflow look like? Does the Node version on the runner match with your local environment? Should there be a call to ‘npm install’ before you build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked the Workflow in your repo and I see that you are running the following commands:

```
...
- run: npm install
- run: npm run build --prefix client
...
```

According to this, the `npm run build --prefix client` will run the build under the `client` directory, but the first command installs dependencies under the root folder. The `build` just can't find dependencies since it's not installed in the `client` directory.

So you need to change your install command to use the prefix also:

```
npm install --prefix client
```

To read more about prefixes, visit the [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#prefix).

---

Alternatively, you can use the `working-directory` keyword to specify the working directory of where to run the command:

```
- name: Install
  working-directory: client
  run: npm install

- name: Build
  working-directory: client
  run: npm run build
```